# Botão copiar com id de input dinamico

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma página com vários links e para cada link tem um botão copiar.
Como faço para escrever o código de botão copiar quando o id do input é dinamico "rand()"?

```
php
<?php
$id_input = rand();
?>

html

<input type="text" id="<?php echo $id_input; ?>" name="<?php echo $id_input; ?>" value='<?php echo $http; ?>'> <button name='<?php echo "btn_" . $id_input; ?>' onClick="copiarTexto()"></button>        

java
<script>
  function copiarTexto() {
    var textoCopiado = document.getElementById("<?=$id_input?>");
    textoCopiado.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Link Copiado: " + textoCopiado.value);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o **id** como parâmetro da função **"copiarTexto"**:

```
<button onclick="copiarTexto(<?= $id_input ?>)">Copiar</button>
```

Depois é só usar no **getElementById** para pegar o value.

```
    function copiarTexto(id)
    {
        let texto = document.getElementById(id)
        alert(texto.value)
    }
```

[Aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) você pode encontrar mais sobre o assunto.